# Jquery datatables filtering with select/Filter exact values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, filtering

So I have a table in which I use select box in the tfooter. Actually I use datatables plugin to create the table.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#simpleClassTable').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "{% url 'simpleclasssummaryjson' %}",
        "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 20, -1], [5, 10, 20, "All"]],
        "aoColumnDefs": [],
        "aaSorting": [[4,'desc'], [3,'desc']],
        "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "Search all columns:"
        },
     })
});
```

In table footer I have select box

```
    <tfoot>   
    <tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>
        <select id='filterOnDiff'>
            <option value="">All</option> 
            <option value="2">2</option> 
            <option value="5">5</option> 
            <option value="21">21</option> 
            <option value="22">22</option> 
            <option value="25">25</option> 
        </select>
    </th>
    ...
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
```

I defined a jquery function which is filtering table by select box values.

```
$('#filterOnDiff').on('change', function() {
    var table = $('#simpleClassTable').DataTable();
    table.column(1).
        search($(this).val()).
           draw();
});
```

All works fine. For exact values (lets say 21, 22,..) But it does not work with value "2".

That is if I am selecting value 2 then table is returning values "2", "21", "22", ...

**So my question is how to change the javascript function to filter to exact value?**

Here is the correct filtering with 21. [image]

Here is the incorrect filtering with 2. [image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [search API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search()) as regular expression, wrapping search value with leading `^` and trailing `$` and providing second argument as `true` and third one as `false`. Here is a [similar example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html).

So, try to rewrite your code to:

```
$('#filterOnDiff').on('change', function() {
  var table = $('#simpleClassTable').DataTable();
  table.column(1).
    search(this.value && `^${this.value}$`, true, false).
      draw();
});
```

plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/jCKGSY?p=preview, try to filter 'ID' column